# find the longest consecutive set of vowels in a string

Tags: r

Trying to find the longest consecutive set of vowels in a string.

I have a very long string.

```
random_letters <- readr::read_lines("https://byuistats.github.io/M335/data/randomletters.txt")
```

I have stripped the string of all spaces and periods.

`random_letters %>%  str_replace_all(., fixed(" "), "") %>% str_replace_all('\\.', '')`

I am now trying to find every single time a vowel, or combination of vowels occurs, and then identify the longest one.

so if the string looked like

```
string <- c("abcnduakngoaibhui")
```

the output would be

```
"a" "ua" "oai" "ui
```

Comment: You say "find the longest" and then suggest the expected output would be all of them. Do you know how to continue from there?

Comment: Sorry about that. I said find the longest cause that's what I was trying to do, but showing all of them would be okay since I could work with that too. Only showing the longest is okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R you could use `strsplit`:

```
 strsplit(string, '[^aeiou]+')
[[1]]
[1] "a"   "ua"  "oai" "ui"
```

Also You could use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(string, "[aeiou]+")
[[1]]
[1] "a"   "ua"  "oai" "ui"
```

These gives you a list, since they are vectorized meaning that the string can be a vector:

```
string <- c("abcnduakngoaibhui", "aeityuioaiii")
strsplit(string, '[^aeiou]+')
[[1]]
[1] "a"   "ua"  "oai" "ui" 

[[2]]
[1] "aei"     "uioaiii"
```